# Smart TV Browser and Meteor.js App

Tags: browser, meteor, smart-tv

I tried running a Meteor.js app on my Samsung Smart TV (2013 I think) stock Internet Browser and received "out of memory errors".  I'm interested in see if any can or has run a Meteor.Js app on some of the latest SMART TV Browsers...

eg.  I tried a running a sample app to test Meteor.js Streams package...

Just curious...thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Try turning off some of the apps running. Also, just to start, I would recommend trying one of the example Meteor apps with no additional Meteorite packages

Answer (score 0):

I am doing some work against LG Smart TVs and have been debugging out-of-memory errors as well. Two major things: large client side minimongo databases are all in-memory and can contribute to the issue. Usually just limiting how much you publish on the server should help. Secondly, images. Those are likely your main culprits. These TVs don't understand single page apps too well and will only flush memory consumed by images when the page reloads.